# Put data into a list from webpage (splinter)

Tags: python, browser, splinter

I am doing a little bot, that should give information from website (ebay) and put into a list using splinter and python. My first lines of code:

```
from splinter import Browser
with Browser() as browser:
url = "http://www.ebay.com"
browser.visit(url)
browser.fill('_nkw', 'levis')
button = browser.find_by_id('gh-btn')
button.click()
```

[image: Ebay.com]
How I can put information that in red frame to list, using information from web page?

Like : [["Levi Strauss & Co. 513 Slim Straight Jean Ivory Men's SZ", 12.99, 0], ["Levi 501 Jeans Mens Original Levi's Strauss Denim Straight", 71.44, "Now"], ["Levis 501 Button Fly Jeans Shrink To Fit Many Sizes", [$29.99, $39.99]]]

Comment: I would suggest using [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) and [BS](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/)

Comment: @Aki003 Can you explain, how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not perfect answer, but it should work.
first thing install these two module
[requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) and [BS4](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/):

> pip install requests
>
> pip install beautifulsoup4

```
import requests
import json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

#setting up the headers
headers={
'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36',
'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8',
'Referer': 'https://www.ebay.com/',
'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.8',
'Host': 'www.ebay.com',
'Connection': 'keep-alive',
'Cache-Control': 'max-age=0',
}
#setting up my proxy, you can disable it
proxy={
'https':'127.0.0.1:8888'
}

#search terms
search_term='armani'

#request session begins
ses=requests.session()

#first get home page so to set cookies
resp=ses.get('https://www.ebay.com/',headers=headers,proxies=proxy,verify=False)

#next get the search term page to parse request
resp=ses.get('https://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_trksid=p2374313.m570.l1313.TR12.TRC2.A0.H0.X'+search_term+'.TRS0&_nkw='+search_term+'&_sacat=0',
headers=headers,proxies=proxy,verify=False)


soup = BeautifulSoup(resp.text, 'html.parser')
items=soup.find_all('a', { "class" : "vip" })
price_items=soup.find_all('span', { "class" : "amt" })

final_list=list()

for item,price in zip(items,price_items):
    try:
        title=item.getText()
        price_val=price.find('span',{"class":"bold"}).getText()
        final_list.append((title,price_val))
    except Exception as ex:
        pass
    
print(final_list)
```

This is the output that I got

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @Aki003, Something like this

```
def get_links(ebay_url):
    page = requests.get(ebay_url).text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
    links = []
    for item in soup.find_all('a'):
        links.append(item.get('href'))
    return(links)
```

You can scrape for any other element on the webpage. Check the [beautifulsoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/z) documentation.

Comment: Thank you very much